# How to initialize a time in daterangepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, daterangepicker

My date range picker is in the following. How to set a time on loading how?

```
$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
        "singleDatePicker": true,
        "timePicker": true,
        "startDate": "08/30/2017",
        "endDate": "09/05/2017"

},
```

Comment: I am asking about daterangepicker not datetimepicker or datepicker. Anyway thank you

Comment: Not familiar with the `daterangepicker`, but maybe you could do something like: `$('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({ startDate: new Date(), [... rest of your params]});`